# Java not running on Windows server 2019

Tags: java, windows, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I'm on this for a really long time. I need to have JRE 6 running on a new nonactivated Windows server 2019 essentials to be able to use a very old remote controller for some servers (old IBM & DELL racks).

No matter what version of java I install, it's just not running. I don't see it in the bottom right corner or in the running services. I know it seems very basic but I couldn't find a solution online.

Am I missing something? All I could find online is suggestions to add java to the environment variables but that is for a different issue. I tried it desperately but of course it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: First use command prompt to check if ide is working on your computer or not

Comment: The only thing you should do is open a terminal and type `java -version`.

Comment: Try setting the java to the environment variable and run your java application.

Comment: Try the command suggested by @Olivier. That will tell you whether Java is accessible or not. That means environment variable is set properly or not. Also, make sure environment variable must have bin location in the path, that's where java.exe is.

Comment: How do you know its running or its not? May be its hiding from you on purpose. EDIT: Please share some relevant information. There is no code, no stacktrace, no process info etc to make a suitable answer. or even help someone who is having a similar problem

Comment: SOLVED: had to install the same version of JRE for 32 bits

Answer (score 2):

Java, or more precisely the [Java Virtual Machine (JVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), is not something that runs in the background. JVM is used to start specific applications. How the `java.exe` or similar executable will be resolved and invoked will depend on the specific application.

What you usually see in the Windows task tray area is a the Java update checker (`Jucheck.exe`). Whether or not this service is present will depend on selected installation options. It also might be that a very old Java 6 simply does not ship it.